# Flutter build stream builder from app start

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, themes

I need to load the saved themes from shared preference async from app start. After it loaded, replace the placeholder two themes. But below code failed because even it loaded the results for several themes, the app always displays the two themes.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final bloc = AppThemeBloc();
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bloc.getAppThemes();
    return buildApp();
  }

  Widget buildApp() {
    return StreamBuilder<List<AppTheme>>(
        stream: bloc.subject.stream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AppTheme>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ThemeProvider(
              saveThemesOnChange: true,
              loadThemeOnInit: true,
              themes: snapshot.data,
              child: MaterialApp(
                home: ThemeConsumer(
                  child: HomePage(),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return ThemeProvider(
              saveThemesOnChange: true,
              loadThemeOnInit: true,
              themes: [
                AppTheme.light(),
                AppTheme.dark(),
              ],
              child: MaterialApp(
                home: ThemeConsumer(
                  child: HomePage(),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see shared preferences referenced in your code example. Regardless, why not just load the two themes from shared preferences before the call to `runApp`? The native iOS and Android launch screens will be visible to the user and it won't take very long to load the themes from shared preferences. It will save you a lot of complicated code!

Answer (score 0):

After the data is received and the streambuilder is refreshed which updates the state so build function is being executed again thus calling:

```
bloc.getAppThemes();
```

again which waits for any data to pass in the stream returning your placeholder themes, place bloc.getAppThemes function in the initState function:

```
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   bloc.getAppThemes();
}
```